# Update saving partial data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, nosql

```
var CandidateProfileSchema = new Schema({
  Skills: {
    programmingLang: [{text: String}],
    scriptingLang:  [{text: String}],
    tools:  [{text: String}],
    ide:  [{text: String}],
  },
  //more fields
});

exports.updateOptPrefs = function(req, res) {
  console.log( req.body );
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  CandidateProfile.findOne({userId:req.params.id}, function (err, candidateProfile) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!candidateProfile) { return res.send(404); }

    candidateProfile.Skills.programmingLang= req.body.Skills.programmingLang;
    candidateProfile.Skills.scriptingLang= req.body.Skills.scriptingLang;
    candidateProfile.Skills.tools=req.body.Skills.tools;
    candidateProfile.Skills.ide=req.body.Skills.ide;
    //.... other fields
    candidateProfile.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, candidateProfile);
    });
  });
};
```

Somehow this is copying only the programmingLang field in the mongodb document. We have spent about 5 hours on this issue and would be very glad if someone can point the mistake we are making here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com/) extend:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
exports.updateOptPrefs = function(req, res) {
    if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
    CandidateProfile.findOne({userId:req.params.id}, function (err, candidateProfile) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        if(!candidateProfile) { return res.send(404); }
        candidateProfile = _.extend(candidateProfile, req.body);
        candidateProfile.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            return res.json(200, candidateProfile);
        });
    });
 };
```

Comment: or if you want to just update the skills: 
`candidateProfile.Skills = _.extend(candidateProfile.Skills , req.body.Skills);`

Comment: I have a larger candidateProfile schema
CandidateProfile ({  
  Skills: {....}
  other: [{
    typeExp:String,
    organization: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    role: String,
    description: String,
    achievements: String
  }],
  //More fields

I am basically updating each part like Skills or Other Exp in a call each. When I use your suggested merge on Skills portion above it works great. I try to use the same code for Other Exp as above and I get 2 rows with the same data. 

Can you see the problem ?

Comment: Can you share your code for the route handler , basically you can update any property inside your schema using: 
`candidateProfile['propertyName'] = _.extend(candidateProfile['propertyName'] , req.body['propertyName']);` and replace propertyName with whatever you want to update from the req.body

Comment: Please check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771633/mongoose-lodash-extend-copying-array-of-object-incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use mongoose update and $set ?

```
CandidateProfile.update( {'userId' : req.params.id}, 
                         {$set : {Skills.programmingLang:req.body.Skills.programmingLang, ...}}, function(err){
```