# Mongoose + lodash extend copying array of object incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I have this schema

```
var CandidateProfileSchema = new Schema({
  OtherExp: [{
    typeExp:String,
    organization: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    role: String,
    description: String,
    achievements: String
  }],
  //more fields
});
```

This is my controller function called for put / update of OtherExp fields in the schema.

```
exports.updateOtherExp = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  CandidateProfile.findOne({userId:req.params.id}, function (err, candidateProfile) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!candidateProfile) { return res.send(404); }

    candidateProfile.other= _.extend(candidateProfile.other, req.body.other);

    candidateProfile.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, candidateProfile);
    });
  });
};
```

My data is say 
Row 1: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,, a6, a7
Row 2: b1, b2, b3, b4, b5,, b6, b7

Problem is data getting saved to my mongodb collection is a repeat of the first row
Row 1: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,, a6, a7
Row 2: a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,, a6, a7

Can anyone see what might be the issue ?
The same code works fine for other parts of my schema where I have no nesting of the data like in this one.

This is from my candidateProfile / index.js

```
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.put('/:id/skills', controller.updateSkills);
router.put('/:id/otherExp', controller.updateOtherExp);
```

Comment: I would use node inspector to make sure that `candidateProfile.other` and `req.body.other` are the values you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I've just wasted 1 hour on similar issue. I've used `_.assign{In}()`, then `_.merge()` then tried also `Document#set()` i've always ended with repeated entries in array.

The workaround that works for me

- assign `[]` to any array that is about to be set
- then assign whole tree using `doc.set(attrs)`

Example (in my case, `some_problematic_array` caused same strange behaviuour as in question):

```
var attrs = _.pick(req.body, [
    'name',
    'tags', // ...
    "some_problematic_array"
]);
var doc = ///... ;

if( attrs.some_problematic_array ) doc.some_problematic_array = [];
                                      ^^^^ ***workaround***
doc.set(attrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a typo: 
if you want to update OtherExp in your candidateProfile, it should be something like this

```
candidateProfile.OtherExp = _.extend(candidateProfile.OtherExp, req.body.OtherExp);`
candidateProfile.save(//... etc)
```

Comment: The name is otherExp but that is not the point. We are able to push data into the mongodb database but its the first experience info twice instead of data of two different experiences. I have tested the request body to confirm we are pushing the correct data in.

Comment: Can you try _.merge instead of extend

Comment: also what's the data being sent like , is it an element you want to add to the array of OtherExp , or is it an array to replace the OtherExp? because if you just want to add to the array all what you have to do is push the new element `candidateProfile.OtherExp.push(req.body.experience)`

Comment: This is what I am getting in my db
{ typeExp: 'Research',
  organization: 'bleh',
  startDate: '01/01/2015',
  endDate: '05/01/2015',
  role: 'bleh',
  description: 'bleh',
  achievements: 'bleh',
  _id: 54a9fcf541aa72381548c9d6 },{ typeExp: 'Research',
  organization: 'bleh',
  startDate: '01/01/2015',
  endDate: '05/01/2015',
  role: 'bleh',
  description: 'bleh',
  achievements: 'bleh',
  _id: 54a9fcf541aa72381548c9d6 }

Comment: What I am expecting is 
{ typeExp: 'Research',
  organization: 'bleh',
  startDate: '01/01/2015',
  endDate: '05/01/2015',
  role: 'bleh',
  description: 'bleh',
  achievements: 'bleh',
  _id: 54a9fcf541aa72381548c9d6 },{ typeExp: 'Intern',
  organization: 'meh',
  startDate: '06/01/2015',
  endDate: '10/01/2015',
  role: 'meh',
  description: 'meh',
  achievements: 'meh',
  _id: 54a9fcf541aa72381548c9d6 }

Comment: _merge or extend give the same result. I might be doing something stupid but I have verified the incoming data so the error is from the controller code and not the front end.
Push will not work as user may want to delete previously entered data.I am basically trying to add new objects in the array of objects that make up otherExp in my candidateProfile document.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose models with nested enumerables mess up with lodash merge or extend.

Try first aggregating your data before assigning.

```
var data = _.merge(candidateProfile.toJSON(), req.body);
candidateProfile.other = _.extend(candidateProfile.other, data.other);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mess up"?